# Prevent non-admin to add/create new pages

Tags: pages

I would like to prevent non-admin users from creating/adding new pages on Wordpress. Is that doable in functions.php?

Comment: Yes it is possible, only Administrators and Editors can edit pages. So would like to remove that functionality from Editors?

Comment: Yes Nath. Maybe I should correct the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the capability using [remove_cap](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap), [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) you can see a list per role of all capabilities available, the one you want would be `edit_pages`, so this will work for the editor rol, which has that capability:

```
$role = get_role( 'editor' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_pages' );
```

you may want `publish_pages`, `edit_posts`,`publish_posts` too, check the table for the rols that have those capabilities, take into account that you need to do this 1 time only, the `remove_cap` will modify the value in the database from 1 to 0, so run it only 1 time, here is how an `WP_Role object` looks:

```
WP_Role Object
(
    [name] => subscriber
    [capabilities] => Array
        (
            [read] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
        )

)
```

as you can see a subscriber can only `read`, notice that only the capabilities with `1` (true) will be saved.

You can also create your own [rol](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) and add capabilities to it, thats another topic though =]